# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rumba'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on Linux

Tags: mysql, access-denied

I have tried multiple solutions from Stackoverflow  but couldn't solve it.

Comment: Hint: "password: NO" means you forgot to supply a password.

Comment: Check: 1.If the database is on the computer you are using to connect, or if its remote (you are connecting to a database on localhost, means that the database should be on the same machine that you are working with. 2.Whether the password is required or not to login